# Connected subsets of $C[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

I was solving the following question:

> Let $S=\{f \in C[0,1] \ \colon\int_0^1f(t)\ dt=0 \}$. Then is $S$ connected in $(C[0,1],d_\infty)$?

Here $d_{\infty}$ is the standard sup-metric.

Then the following question came to my mind:

> Can anything be said about the connected subsets of $C[0,1]$?

To be precise, I'm want to know if there are any pre-existing generalizations or characterizations that I am unaware of. It'd be really helpful even if I could be guided towards any reference or paper that might be helpful.

Comment: S is even  vector subspace,

Comment: @Ashkan, I am aware. My question is something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convex sets are (path-)connected, of course, and I think your set $S$ is:$f,g \in S$ means that $uf + (1-u)g$ is also in $S$ for all $u \in [0,1]$. In your case it's even a linear subspace (which are of course also connected).

I think you have to look at it at a case to case basis. You cannot expect a nice characterisation of connected subsets of $C[0,1]$ as this contains all spaces$\mathbb{R}^n$ as subspaces, and there are all sorts of weird sets there (lakes of Wada, irredicible continua, Warsaw circle etc.) and $C[0,1]$ thus contains all of these and more. Infinite-dimensional spaces have a lot of room for "weirdness". In the simple case of $\mathbb{R}$ (as low-dimensional as it gets for connected spaces) the only connected subsets are intervals, but already in the plane it gets complicated; whole books have been written about plane continua.